# Apache POI and CellType

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am a little bit lost with version of

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
```

I tried version 3.17, 4.0.0 and 5.0.0.

```
if (c.getCellType () == CellType.NUMERIC.getCode())
{
}
```

or

```
if (c.getCellTypeEnum () == CellType.NUMERIC)
{
}
```

I was not able to get a code free of deprecation or type-errors :-(

I am using Eclipe with Maven and Java 11. After the cange of the version I did "Update Project" to update Maven.

Answer (score 5):

In `apache poi 3.17` `Cell.getCellType` returns a `int` but is deprecated. `Cell.getCellTypeEnum` returns a `CellType`. See [apache poi 3.17 API: Interface Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html).

So using `apache poi 3.17` it must be

```
if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
```

In `apache poi` greater than or equal version `4.0.0` `Cell.getCellType` returns a `CellType`.  `Cell.getCellTypeEnum` also returns a `CellType` but is deprecated. See [apache poi 4.0 API: Interface Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html).

So using `apache poi` greater than or equal version `4.0.0` it must be

```
if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC)
```

Comment: I tried that but Eclipse did not accept that to remove deprecations.

Comment: @chris01: Then Eclipse does something wrong. Or you are mixing different `apache poi` versions in one project.